# Add static library to pod target (Linked Frameworks and Libraries) programmatically in pod file

Tags: ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I want to automate adding a static library file (.a) to target in xoce
This process is easy doing it by hand:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbE3oku744c&feature=youtu.be

I think the best way to do this is within the pod file.

But I don't know how to handle it in detail.

```rb
post_install do |installer|

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

        if target.name == 'Pods-EVORecording-EVORecording-Movesense'

        # here I think could be the code for adding the .a file

        end
     end
end
```

It would be create to get some hints to solve this task. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by myself. Here is the solution:

```
post_install do |installer|

  lib_name = "libmds.a"
  lib_path = "Movesense/IOS/Movesense/Release-iphoneos"

  # get ref of lib file
  path = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/Pods/" + lib_path + "/" + lib_name
  movesense_ref = installer.pods_project.reference_for_path(path)

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    # find the right target
    if target.name == 'EVORecording-iOS'
      # add libmds.a file to build files
      build_phase = target.frameworks_build_phase
      build_phase.add_file_reference(movesense_ref)

      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # add library search paths
        config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ["$(inherited)", "$(PROJECT_DIR)/" + lib_path]

      end
    end
  end
end
```